# Simple WPF Binding fails to work

Tags: c#, user-interface, binding

```
private void BindFields()
{
    m_QuantityBinding = new Binding("Quantity");
    m_QuantityBinding.Source = m_LotData;

    txtBoxQuantity.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, m_QuantityBinding);
}

private void LoadLotData()
{
    m_PrioInterface = new PriorityInterface.PriorityInterface();

    m_LotData = m_PrioInterface.GetLotInfo(txtSysLotNo.Text);

    m_QuantityBinding = new Binding("Quantity");
    m_QuantityBinding.Source = m_LotData;

    txtBoxQuantity.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, m_QuantityBinding);
}
```

the above binding works only if i redo the binding after each call to GetLotInfo ...
why cant i just set the binding at the begining of the app using BindFields ?
i suspect that the reason is that the GetLotInfo returns a new object each time ...
can i get pass that so that i'll bind only once ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you assing the `.Source` property of your Binding instance

```
m_QuantityBinding.Source = m_LotData;
```

the binding is bound to the particular instance that was stored at that time in your field `m_LotData`. 
In case you assign a new instance to `m_LotData`, wich you do here:

```
m_LotData = m_PrioInterface.GetLotInfo(txtSysLotNo.Text);
```

`m_QuantityBinding` would not know unless you set the `.Source` anwew.